# Why I need both relationship and foreign key for Many to One relationship?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

In the docs for [SQLAlchemy for Many to One](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-one) relationships it shows the following example:

```
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    child_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('child.id'))
    child = relationship("Child")

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
```

**Many parents for a single child.** Then, when if we create a `Parent`, we need to populate `child_id` and `child`, which seems kind of redundant? Is this mandatory, or what's the purpose of each thing?

```
child = Child()
Parent(child_id=child, child=child)
```

Also, in Flask-SQLAlchemy, there is [this example for a simple relationship](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/quickstart/#simple-relationships) in which it creates a post like this:

```
Post(title='Hello Python!', body='Python is pretty cool', category=py)
```

without providing a `category_id`. If I replicate that scenario, `category_id` value is `None`.

For the purpose of creating new objects like `Parent(child=child)`, would it be enough to add `foreign_keys=[child_id]` or does it have further implications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not mandatory; you do not need to populate both. Setting the foreign key to the related instance can be an error waiting to manifest itself. The only thing you need to do is

```
child = Child()
parent = Parent(child=child)
```

After this `parent.child_id` is `None`, but they represent the object part of ORM just fine. `parent.child` is a reference to the created `child`. They have not been persisted to the database and have no identity, other than their Python object ID. Only when you add them to a `Session` and flush the changes to the database do they receive an identity, due to them using generated surrogate keys. Here is where the mapping from the object world to the relational world happens. SQLAlchemy automatically fills in `parent.child_id`, so that their relationship is recorded in the database as well (note that this is not what "relational" in relational model means).

Returning to the example, adding some printing helps keep track of what happens and when:

```
child = Child()
parent = Parent(child=child)
print(parent.child_id)  # None
session.add(parent)
session.flush()  # Send changes held in session to DB
print(parent.child_id)  # The ID assigned to child
```

You can also reverse the situation: you might have the ID of an existing `Child`, but not the actual object. In that case you can simply assign `child_id` yourself.

So, to answer the title: you do not need the ORM `relationship` in order to have a DB foreign key relationship, but you can use it to map the DB relationship to the object world.

Comment: I see, so, the purpose is to relate in advance the objects so once they are persisted, SQLAlchemy can fill the _id fields properly. Thanks !